# Customize MoreNavigationController's Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to make the more view to match my app theme

[image]

The table cells are not changing background color. I have tried almost all the answers here and blogs over the internet.

```
tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

I have used the above code to achieve the current scenario shown in image.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.homeTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "Banner", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Banner")
    self.homeTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "Heading", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Heading")
    self.homeTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ThumblessList", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ThumblessList")
    self.homeTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MapCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MapCell")
    self.homeTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CallButton", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CallButton")
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What do you want your cells to look like? Also consider including more code. At least your Table View datasource methods.

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
I do not have a dataSource configured for this. I have put the above code in my first View controller's viewDidLoad().
The cells need to have a black background.

Comment: Are these static cells you have configured using xibs?

Comment: These are automatically generated cells when I add more than 5 items in the tab bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new view controller and adding that as a 5th tab item for iPhones. For Ipads i created a separate storyboard without the new view controller.

Thanks :)
Sworoop

Answer (score 3):

This is a very late answer, but I could not find a single solution to this problem anywhere online, even though setting the colour of the table view and the cells in the moreNavaigationController of a UITabBarController should be something you can do in the storyboard. I feel like this is an oversight from the Swift/xcode devs.

That said, in the `viewDidAppear` method of your `UITabBarController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if let moreTableView = moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view as? UITableView {

        moreTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.YOURCOLOUR

        for cell in moreTableView.visibleCells {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.YOURCOLOUR
        }
    }
}
```

This code will not work if you do it in the `viewDidLoad` method. I hope this code helps someone who is struggling to find a solution!

Comment: This works but when you go landscape and have items that go off the screen — they turn back to white background.  Any work around for this situation?

Comment: how did it work? I'm using xamarin forms but unable to achieve this.

Comment: As stated this won't work for cells that are not yet visible in table view.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue and want to share my approach to solve this problem. Maybe it will be helpful for someone else...

1. Create a holder for the more UITableView data source:

   @property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id  moreDataSource;
2. Somewhere in the code do the following:

   if([tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view isKindOfClass:UITableView.class]){

   ```
    UITableView *moreTable = (UITableView*)moreNavController.topViewController.view;
    self.moreDataSource = moreTable.dataSource;
    moreTable.dataSource = self;
   ```

   }
3. implement methods of the `UITableViewDataSource`:

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [self.moreDataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.moreDataSource tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return cell;
}
```